# Hits and Home Runs Conditional Probability

Tags: probability, statistics, bayes-theorem

#### Situation

Learning and trying to understand conditional probability by applying it to a sample set of baseball game statistics.

#### Data

G (Games) : 190,313

AB (Hitting Attempts) : 680,024

H (Hits) :  205,837

HR (Home Runs) : 16,417

#### Probabilities

P(H) = H / AB = 0.30269 = 30.37%

P(HR) = HR / H = 0.07976 = 7.98%

#### Conditional Probability:

P(H and HR) = P(H) * P(HR | H)

P(HR | H) = P(H and HR) / P(H)

#### Goal

P(HR | H) = ?

Determine the probability of hitting a Home Run, given that a Hit occurred.

#### Questions

- Not certain how to apply conditional probability to determine the result.
- These seem like dependent events since Home Runs is impacted by the number of Hits, so not sure how that impacts the outcome.
- Does Baye's Theorem need to be applied in this case? If not, in would it be necessary?

Comment: You don't need anything fancy for that one: (number of home runs)/(number of hits).

Comment: @EthanBolker: Thank you! 
Is it because one event is dependent on the other? 
How do you know when Conditional Probability needs to be applied or not?

Comment: You don't need Bayes rule when one event is a subset of the other. These events are indeed dependent: if you know it was a home run then you know it was a hit. All you need now is the fraction. When the events overlap (neither a part of the other) you have to think about conditional probability.